# Common legend for sub float

Tags: subfloats, legend

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{a.jpeg}%
        }   
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{b.jpeg}%
        }\\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{c.jpeg}%
        }
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{d.jpeg}%
        }\\
        \caption{comman legend.}
        \label{3}
    \end{figure}
```

How to include comman legend for the subfigs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could have a look on this page: https://fr.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/07/thesis-series-pt3.html

Comment: Do you want captions for the subfloats?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from writing something between your figures and the common caption. You enter some Text directly, put it in a `minipage` or use a `tabular`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-a.jpg}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-b.jpg}}\\
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-c.jpg}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image.jpg}}\\[2ex]
Some Text can go here, but it is of course centered. And it extends to the
full text width.

\vspace{2ex}
\begin{minipage}{9cm}
Or you can put it in a mini page with the appropriate width. Or, as shown below,
you can use a tabular.
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2ex}
\begin{tabularx}{9cm}{@{}lX@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Legend:}}\\
top left:     & nice gray image with the letter A and some lines \\
top right:    & nice gray image with the letter B and some lines\\
bottom left:  & nice gray image with the letter C and some lines\\
bottom right: & nice gray image with the word Image and some lines
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comman caption.}
\label{3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `figure` environment only makes its content float and its caption will (usually) start with *Figure*. The contents can be nearly anything you want.